# Простой файловый менеджер на Mono под Linux

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, mono, .net

Необходимо написать простейший проводник или файловый менеджер, который будет работать с НМЖД и внешним USB накопителем. Должны быть функции копирования, вставки и удаления. В плане GUI на винформах это возможно реализовать при помощи mono и не является проблемой. На данном этапе столкнулся с не пониманием. При работе в ОС Windows проблем нет, так как я могу свободно использовать WMI и получать доступ к ресурсам и тем же событиям при подключении отключении внешнего накопителя. А вот как быть в ОС Линукс используя mono? 
Вот пример который я сделал для Windows, здесь реализован пока только просмотр:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так я читаю диски:

```
//Get Drive list
ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = getDrives();
foreach ( ManagementObject mo in queryCollection)
{
    ...
}
```

В качестве события использован:

```
System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs
```

Для отображения накопителей и при изменении их количества.
Посоветуйте пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Возможно, если я правильно понял вопрос, стоит копать в сторону кроссплатформенного фреймворка: .net standart или .net core

Comment: На данный момент даже думаю что проблема в событие при подключении внешнего накопителя.

Comment: Libusb под linux, писать на C/C++ функционал поиска/открытия/чтения/записи итд

Comment: Используйте `DriveInfo.GetDrives` для получения всех накопителей (на Mono тоже работает, вроде). А вот событие подключения/отключения нужно ловить как-то ещё.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov DriveInfo.GetDrives Вы правы - работает. Практически все работает, кроме событий. Но как уже написали выше, пошел копать в сторону libusb. Уже удалось отловить событие подключения, отключения. Так же пока не ясно, при подключении, работать с файлами или методами чтения записи libusb, и как создавать безопасное отключение накопителя.

Comment: А ещё подумайте, как ловить вставку/извлечение оптического диска (CD/DVD) в привод. ;)

Comment: О, точно! Сейчас задам новый вопрос на SO =)

Comment: @NewView диски не только усб бывают, но ещё и сетевые и сата можно включать на ходу.

Answer (score 3):

**DBUS**

Если в системе присутствует `Udisks`, то хорошим вариантом будет отслеживание подключения дисков по `dbus`.

http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/ch02.html

Не нахожу сигнала на добавление диска, но есть сигнал об изменении конфигурации - можно перечитать.

Отследить подключение дисков можно в `gvfs` также по `dbus`. Есть методы получить список и можно подписаться на сигналы подключения-отключения.

```
gdbus introspect --session --dest org.gtk.vfs.Daemon --object-path /org/gtk/vfs/mounttracker   --recurse

 ....
  interface org.gtk.vfs.MountTracker {
    methods:
      LookupMount(in  (aya{sv}) mount_spec,
                  out (sossssssbay(aya{sv})ay) mount);
      LookupMountByFusePath(in  ay fuse_path,
                            out (sossssssbay(aya{sv})ay) mount);
      MountLocation(in  (aya{sv}) mount_spec,
                    in  (so) mount_source);
      ListMounts(out a(sossssssbay(aya{sv})ay) mounts);
      ListMounts2(in  b user_visible_only,
                  out a(sossssssbay(aya{sv})ay) mounts);
      RegisterMount(in  o obj_path,
                    in  s display_name,
                    in  s stable_name,
                    in  s x_content_types,
                    in  s icon,
                    in  s symbolic_icon,
                    in  s prefered_filename_encoding,
                    in  b user_visible,
                    in  (aya{sv}) mount_spec,
                    in  ay default_location);
      UnregisterMount(in  o obj_path);
      ListMountTypes(out as mount_types);
      ListMountableInfo(out a(ssasib) mountables);
      RegisterFuse();
    signals:
      Mounted((sossssssbay(aya{sv})ay) mount);
      Unmounted((sossssssbay(aya{sv})ay) mount);
    properties:
  };
};
```

**Файлы**

Самый "железный" и простой метод это смотреть содержимое файла `/proc/mounts/` и папки `/dev/disks/by-id/`

**UDEV**

Запустить `udevadm monitor` и ловить события или сишные вызовы.

**DMESG**

Смотреть лог `dmesg` на события ядра.

Comment: + хорошие решение, но по опыту, возня с д-шиной такой геморрой... :)

Comment: если писать сразу асинхронный код - то быстро втягиваешься..)

Comment: Я так понимаю libusb отлавливает события именно подключения устройства, но он не знает, как монтируется, какой путь и имя накопителя или USB устройства?

Comment: libusb вообще ничего не знает. а сопоставить id на usb и блочное устройство будет вообще тяжко. Смотрите в gvfs - там всё подробнее и структурнее.

Comment: udisk к сожалению нет... Но я четко знаю что у системы будет один порт и монтирование идет по адресу /media/usb1.  Можно конечно захардкодить типо такого - ` var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
            .Where(drive => drive.IsReady && drive.Name == "/media/usb0");`

Comment: может тогда смотреть /proc/mounts ? это порще

Comment: Скажите, я вот совсем в Линуксе не разбираюсь. Как это можно сделать? Через ioctl? Или написать на Си свою либу (например для монтирования используя sys/mount.h) собрать в .so и к ней обращаться? Пока решил задачу в лоб, но это попахивает...

Comment: @JDo начните с того чтоб просмотреть файл /proc/mounts

Comment: Inotify для отслеживания изменений подойдет

Comment: Сделал пока через udev, работает как надо. Благодарю за разъяснения!